# Why were these posts deleted by Community ♦?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, moderation

On the question [What's the relationship among the many uses of the name "Praxis" in sci-fi?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/99720/whats-the-relationship-among-the-many-uses-of-the-name-praxis-in-sci-fi), there are several deleted answers that were deleted by the [Community ♦](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) user: [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/99905/51379)<sup>1</sup>, [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/99904/51379), and [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/99907/51379). For example:

[image]

How did this happen? The [Community ♦](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)  user can delete spam and offensive answers if they receive six flags (or a single moderator flag), but in such cases the text of the post will be hidden. A post can also be deleted if it receives six “Recommend Deletion” votes from the review queue, but then it shows the names of the people who deleted it. It must be an automatic process of some sort, of course, but what is the criterion?

<sup><sub>1: All deleted answers only available to 10k+ users.</sub></sup>

Comment: All three answers appear to be from the same user, sock-puppeting after getting their account splatted.

Comment: @Valorum - So the Community user also does automated sockpuppet maintenance?

Comment: @Valorum - Yes, Community is in charge of deleting spam answers. Those answers were not flagged as spam, though. Answers deleted after being flagged as spam are hidden.

Comment: "*A post can also be deleted if it receives six “Recommend Deletion” votes from the review queue, but then it simply shows as “deleted,” without any user (even Community ♦ )*" - Actually, as of about yesterday, this is no longer true. See e.g. [this deleted answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/76993/31394).

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Wow, that *is* new. Was there any sort of announcement, or did this just happen?

Comment: @Adamant No announcement as far as I know, although I suspect there's a few new [meta-tag:status-completed] tags and CM answers on main meta. There have actually been a few new features just recently; it may be that CMs have been rushing to get things completed before the [company meetup next week](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=33170614#33170614).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick look at the [timelines](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/99905/timeline) for these posts shows that these users were ***[destroyed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)***. The fact that there's three in a row with basically the same answer indicates that they were almost certainly **creating sockpuppet accounts for the purposes of posting worthless answers**.

After a user is destroyed, the Community♦ bot goes in and deletes all of their previous answers, which is what you can see.

Comment: Personally I agree with TheifMaster's [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user#comment392499_88994) "*Launch a missile at the user's last-known location when selecting to destroy them"*

Comment: galaxy note 7 can work, no need for missile

Comment: IIRC, only posts with negative scores are deleted when the user is destroyed.

Comment: @Kevin [Nope](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88996/278659), that's for deleted users. When the user is destroyed, *all* their posts go with them.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - On the principle that you only ***destroy*** a user if their entire contribution has been utterly worthless.